# Neo4j Create Unique + Where in

Tags: arrays, neo4j, duplicates, cypher

What is the correct way to use Create Unique and WHERE IN simultaneously?
Or more generaly how to use Create Unique to create as many path as needed from an array of props?

I have tried without success :

```
MATCH (node1) WHERE node1.name = "node1"
CREATE UNIQUE (node1)-[r:`is_tagged`]->(node2:Tag)
WHERE node2.name IN ["Tag1","Tag2"] 
RETURN r
```

I was hopping this cypher would "tag" the node "node1" with the tags "Tag1" and "Tag2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create constraint on :Tag(name);

MATCH (node1:Document) WHERE node1.name = "node1"
FOREACH (t in ["Tag1","Tag2"] |
 MERGE (node2:Tag {name:t})
 CREATE|MERGE (node1)-[:is_tagged]->(node2)
);
```

or with unwind

```
MATCH (node1:Document) WHERE node1.name = "node1"
UNWIND ["Tag1","Tag2"] as t
MERGE (node2:Tag {name:t})
CREATE|MERGE (node1)-[r:is_tagged]->(node2)
RETURN r
```

Comment: Just a curiosity: is the constraint needed, or it's just an optimisation?

Comment: This solution answers my question as it allow to create "tags" node when needed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should first match the `Tag`s and then add the relations:

```
MATCH (node1) WHERE node1.name = "node1"
WITH node1
MATCH (node2:Tag) WHERE node2.name IN ["Tag1","Tag2"]
CREATE UNIQUE node1-[:is_tagged]->node2
```

Comment: I think he optionally wants to create tags too. But if not your solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, your solution is more general, I didn't think about creating new tags.